# Showing Controls from other forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, panel

How can I show a control for example a `Panel` from other forms in my project?

I like to set 1 `Panel` on the first `Form` and  then send  them to another `Form`

How could I realize that?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to show other forms inside of your form? (e.g. change Notepad's parent window to your form) Or are these forms in the way of plugins (specifically purposed and designed for your application)?

Comment: yes!
i have a menu, so when i click on a submenu i show form1 or the panel in the form1 and switching between them , i won't open the form with new From1().Show();

Comment: As Roy's answer states, this is a good use of user controls. Why build a whole form is it isn't going to be used *as* a form?

Comment: "Call a control" is often used in Winforms questions.  Unfortunately it doesn't mean anything.  You call a method, never a control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

call the `form2` passing `form1` reference to it:

...

```
var form2 = new Form2(this);
```

in `form2`:

```
private Form1 formOne;
public Form2(Form1 form1) { 
     formOne = form1; 
}
```

Then,you can write an method like this:

```
void AddControl(string controlName) { 
        var control = formOne.Find(controlName, true).First(); 
        if(control != null) { 
            Controls.Add(control);
        }
}
```

I have not tested it, but I believe that it works. I hope this help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) which can be re-used on multiple forms.